# Kubernetes service load balancer "No route to host" error

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm trying to expose a pod using a load balancer service. The service was created successfully and an external IP was assigned. When I tried accessing the external in the browser the site is no and I got ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. Please see the yaml below:

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: service-api
  name: service-api
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30868
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9080
    name: http
  selector:
    name: service-api
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

I also tried creating the service using kubernetes CLI still no luck.

Comment: can you verify endpoints got created: `kubectl get endpoints`? they should match pod ips

Comment: Yes, the endpoints were created.

Comment: can you verify this works internally? without the load balancer?

Comment: I tried it also using wget but it failed then I  get the No route to host message.

Comment: ugh, does dns work in your cluster? also, what if you access pod directly? does it work?

Comment: Yes the DNS is working on my cluster I have other load balancer services that it working fine. What do you mean by accessing the pod directly? You mean connecting to the pod using kubectl exec? If yes, yes I can connect to the pod.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185020/discussion-between-alec-jones-and-4c74356b41).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like I have a faulty DNS on my k8s cluster. In order to resolve the issue, I have to restart the cluster. But before restarting the cluster, you can also delete all the pods in **kube-system** to refresh the DNS pods and if it's still not working I suggest restarting the cluster.

Comment: There's no such thing as "restarting a cluster" -- you don't restart an entire Kubernetes cluster. Can you edit your answer to be more specific if the solution is to restart something?